# Ethereum Javascript console "short write"

Tags: console, ethereum

Does anyone know what this means? I'm getting it in my ethereum console quite a bit.  It doesn't seem to be breaking anything that I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux it means that you are exceeding the max filesize.
The max file-size in Linux vary depending on the Kernel version (could be 2Gb).
So, it seems that you are doing an operation that is causing the OS to make a very large file.

(If you can share the full context for the error message we can give you more detailed answer.)